How to Prove Homeomorphism Using Pushout Diagrams in CW Complexes?
I am working on understanding how to prove homeomorphisms between topological spaces using pushout diagrams, particularly in the context of CW complexes. My knowledge of category theory is limited, and I am primarily interested in its practical applications to CW complexes.
We only consider topological spaces in this question. Consider the following setup:

Let $X^{n-1} =: X$ be the $(n-1)$-skeleton of a CW complex.
Let $D^n =: Y$ be the $n$-disk, and $\partial D^n =: Z$ its boundary.
Suppose $f$ is an attaching map and $g$ is the inclusion map.
Define $P := (X^{n-1} \sqcup \partial D^n) / (x \sim f(x))$ by the definition of the pushout.

The pushout makes the following diagram commute:

Note that the morphism represented by the dashed arrow in the commutative diagram exists and is unique if all other arrows in the diagram commute. Furthermore, I am familiar with using the universal property of quotient spaces to prove homeomorphisms in CW complexes. For reference, the universal property of quotient spaces makes the following diagram commute:

Recall that $P := (X^{n-1} \sqcup \partial D^n) / \sim$, where $x \sim f(x)$. Let $D := X^{n-1} \sqcup \partial D^n$ and $\pi$ be the quotient map induced by the equivalence relation $\sim$. To prove that $P \cong Q$, one just need to show that $f$ is a quotient map. This result is detailed in Corollary 22.3 of Munkres's book on Topology or here. However, it is not clear whether there is a similar result we can leverage when proving the same in a Pushout diagram.
This brings me to the following question:
Is there a general procedure for proving that two topological spaces $P$ and $Q$ are homeomorphic using pushout diagrams in the context of CW complexes described above, similar to the result mentioned involving universal property of quotient spaces?
Any insights or references to relevant (understandable and motivated) literature would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I don't understand.  What is $Q$?  Is it something specific?  In the universal property, it is to hold for all $Q$ admitting coherent squares.  Are you asking how to prove that two pushouts are homeomorphic?

Q just need to make the pushout diagram commutative. One of my questions is about how to prove that $P \cong Q$ in the general case given the pushout diagram. I will make it more clear by editing my question.

If $Q$ just makes the square commute (e.g., if $Q$ is a 1-point space), it need not be homeomorphic to $P$.

I have edited my question to clarify my specific inquiries. I hope it is now evident what I am asking about.

Your description of the universal property for pushouts, i.e. a picture and the words "the pushout makes the following diagram commute", is defective. There are important quantifiers in the description that you have omitted, starting with "For all topological spaces $Q$..."

@LeeMosher Can you make clear what you meant with the description of pushouts is defective? I specified that it is about CW complexes and it should be clear from that alone that it is about topological spaces if it is about that.

Regarding the question being closed for lack of focus, does that mean I just need to make three separate posts containing one question each?

You should just clarify what you mean IMO. This question is an example of an XY problem: rather than asking "how can I use [pushout diagrams] to prove that [$P$ and $Q$ are homeomorphic]", say precisely what you are trying to prove and what your assumptions are (and maybe what you've tried, and how this involves pushouts).

I am asking for a general procedure like the one I mentioned involving quotient spaces. I have now edited it by mentioning that in the question and I hope it is more clear now.

The definition of the pushout diagram requires that for every $Q$, $j_1$, $j_2$ there exists a unique $u$. You omitted any mention of the necessary quantifiers for every and there exists a unique.

Your "procedure" regarding quotient spaces also doesn't make sense: as Randall said, if $Q$ is a one-point space then $f$ is a quotient map, but this says nothing about $P$... the actual theorems you are referring to assume that $P$ and $\pi$ have specific definitions which you do not mention. Broadly speaking, they make use of the fact that universal cocones are unique up to isomorphism (in this case, both maps satisfy the universal property of the coequaliser of the kernel pair of $f$, although proving this requires some knowledge specific to the category of topological spaces).

@LeeMosher I thought that it was clear from the dashed arrow being in the commutative diagram. I will add that to the question for clarification. Let me know if there is anything else unclear.

@NaïmFavier Regarding Randal's comment on $Q$ being a one-point space, I understand that $P \cong Q$ is not always true. My focus is specifically on proving homeomorphisms when they are known to exist. I will clarify $\pi$ in the question and recapitulate the definition of $P$ to avoid confusion. As for the universal cocone, I am unsure if it is relevant but welcomes answers addressing this after the question is reopened.

"Known to exist"? What is the difference between knowing that $P$ and $Q$ are homeomorphic and having a proof of it? Not being pedantic here, just still genuinely dumbfounded by your question.

I mean, if a homeomorphism exists, it should be provable. I am just looking for tools allowing me to do so with relative ease compared to starting from the definition of a homeomorphism.

Is this the question:  how can I use pushouts to prove that two spaces are homeomorphic?

That may be the question without context.

For the people who down voted this question, could you explain why? I would like to further improve my question by all means.

Your question still seems to be based on a misunderstanding of universal properties. For example, this statement in your discussion of the quotient map diagram is false: To prove that $P \cong Q$, one just need to show that $f$ is a quotient map. Perhaps you have something in your mind that did not make it out your fingers when you typed this post, but, missing quantifiers or other missing information allow for simple counterexamples. In this case, for a counterexample, take $Q$ to be a one point topological space and take $u$ and $f$ to be constant maps.

I am not sure about the counterexample. It seems that when $f$ is the constant map, P consists of only $1$ equivalence class, making it homeomorphic to the one point topological space $Q$.
